# Sphinx IPython extension error - Cannot import name ScriptMagics

Tags: python, ipython, python-sphinx

I'm getting this error when building my Sphinx documentation, after I started using an IPython directive.

```
make html
Running Sphinx v1.6.3

Extension error:
Could not import extension IPython.sphinxext.ipython_console_highlighting (excep
tion: cannot import name ScriptMagics)
```

The extensions that I'm importing in conf.py are:

```
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc',
              'sphinx.ext.autosummary',
              'sphinx.ext.doctest',
              'sphinx.ext.extlinks',
              'sphinx.ext.todo',
              'sphinx.ext.napoleon',
              'IPython.sphinxext.ipython_console_highlighting',
              'IPython.sphinxext.ipython_directive',
              'sphinx.ext.autosectionlabel',
              'sphinx.ext.mathjax',
              'nbsphinx',
              ]
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I think you need to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was update IPython and the error went away.